# Is it possible to keep an a custom Google Actions app (Built into Google Assistant SDK) active all the time?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am building a Google Assistant application but would like to restrict the app from ever exiting. Meaning I just want the experience to be my app. This isn't a public facing app, its personal and on a custom device, like a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no official way to do it that way but there is a trick you can use using the gActions CLI by running:

```
$ gactions preview --action_package mypackage.json --preview_mins 420
```

I'm not sure how far you can push the preview time though. You can find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)